# A quantity measuring weak compactness

Tags: banach-spaces

Let us fix some notations. If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty subsets of a Banach space $X$, we set $d(A,B)=\inf\{\|a-b\|\mid a\in A,b\in B\},\widehat{d}(A,B)=\sup\{d(a,B)\mid a\in A\}.$  Let $A$ be a bounded subset of a Banach space $X$. Set 
$$\omega(A)=\inf\{\widehat{d}(A,K)\mid \emptyset\neq K\subset X \text{ is weakly compact }\},$$ 
and $$\omega_{0}(A)=\inf\{\widehat{d}(A,K):\emptyset\neq K\subset A \text{ is weakly compact }\}.$$ I have the following two questions:

> Question 1. The two quantities $\omega(\cdot)$ and $\omega_{0}(\cdot)$ are equivalent?
>
> Question 2. There exist a space $X$ and a sequence $(A_{n})_{n}$ of bounded subsets of $X$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\omega(A_{n})}{\omega_{0}(A_{n})}=0$?

Comment: I think that you should add some restrictions to your Questions, otherwise the negative answer is easy: let $A$ be the subset consisting of all points with rational coordinates in the unit ball of $\ell_2$. The first quantity is $0$, while the second is not.

Comment: @AugustCleaner: nice example!

Comment: @AugustCleaner:  You are right, August.  This question is trivial in general case.

Comment: Correction: My example is not good as one can consider, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the following weakly compact subset $K_n$ of $A$: The first coordinate is a multiple of $2^{-n-1}$, the second coordinate is a multiple of $2^{-n-2}$, so on, the $n$th coordinate is a multiple of $2^{-2n}$.

Comment: An example which works is the unit sphere of $\ell_2$.

Comment: I would like to mention that if you restrict your question to bounded closed convex sets, it can become more challenging and possibly can be answered using the techniques of Ptak, James and Milman-Milman.